# Deleting from SQL Server ColumnStore gives "Cannot insert duplicate key" error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-delete, columnstore

Our product loads data from CSV files into various tables via the .NET  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy class. 
After a successful load, all data older than a certain timestamp is removed from the database. This is done by executing the following command until no rows are deleted:

```
DELETE TOP (100000) FROM DBO.TBL_DDBB WHERE MeasureDateTime < CAST('2020/04/05 00:00:00' as datetime)
```

This works fine from tables in RowStore format, but when executing this command on a table with a ColumnStore index we get the following error:

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.deleted_bitmap' with
>   unique index 'tuple_key'. The duplicate key value is (98, 0).The
>   statement has been terminated.

The problem **is** reproducible on multiple tables in ColumnStore format on this SQL Server machine, but **not** on other SQL Servers that we have.

I cannot figure out why this happens, and I can't anything on the web mentioning this error. Has anybody seen this before or can anybody tell me how to prevent it?

Version information on the SQL Server used:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU12) (KB4536648) - 13.0.5698.0 (X64)
>   Feb 15 2020 01:47:30   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard
>   Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3  (Build
>   9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Do you have triggers on the tables recording information from deleted rows?

Comment: Nope; no triggers, no constraints, not even secondary indexes. I think the  'dbo.deleted_bitmap'  object the error mentions is a SQL Server construct for dealing with row-deletion in ColumnStores. It's certainly not one of ours.

Comment: See if the row groups containing the data being deleted are closed. Since the delete works on other servers, it could be the difference is due to open versus closed.

Comment: Hi Dan. Good suggestion, but I checked and unfortunately this is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

columnstore : SQL Server marks the row as logically deleted, but doesn't reclaim the physical storage for the row until the index is rebuilt.

So logically till you rebuild index data is there in index.

After delete you have to rebuild index to reclaim key and space.

or ALTER INDEX ... REORGANIZE

More details on [Msdn link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-ver15)

how delete work in column store good page [deleted_bitmap](http://%20%20https://aboutsqlserver.com/2014/05/06/clustered-columnstore-indexes-exploring-delta-store-and-delete-bitmap/)

Comment: This I knew, and given how ColumnStores work that does make sense. But what the link doesn't mention or explains is why this error occurs. My theory is that SQL Server uses the deleted_bitmap to store unique identifers for deleted rows so that a subsequent ALTER INDEX .. REORGANIZE knows what t delete. But if that's true, then the duplicate key error must mean that a row is getting deleted twice. And that's what puzzles me.

Comment: you have top 1000 every time you will be getting same deleted .. just do re index  and you will not face this issue or remove top

Comment: here more detail on deleted_bitmap  https://aboutsqlserver.com/2014/05/06/clustered-columnstore-indexes-exploring-delta-store-and-delete-bitmap/

Comment: @Ide hope this answer.

Comment: "you have top 1000 every time you will be getting same deleted " If what you are saying is true, then that means that the SQL Server delete mechanism is broken for ColumnStore. When you delete a row, SQL Server should act is if that row is not present anymore. This goes for any operation, be it insert, update select or delete.  The DELETE TOP 1000 deletes 1000 rows, so any subsequent DELETE statement will (or rather, should)  ignore the previously deleted rows. I cannot image that this is indeed how Microsoft has created ColumnStores.

Comment: NB: as I've stated in my original question, the DELETE TOP 10000 mechanism works on other SQL Servers. The problem occurs (so far) on only this specific server.